# iif in dimension member (MDX)

Tags: mdx, dimension, iif

I need create a "business rule" on a new metric that consider some values on "condition a" and others values on "condition b" and this condition is before or after a date.

Being more specific: if date is before 2010-11-01, the metric will sum values A + B; if not, the metric will sum values C + D.

My "Period" dimension has like a key the date but in this format 20101101 and I try the follow code:

```
iif(
    [Period].[Period].[Date] < [Period].[Period].[Date].&[20101101],
    (
        ( [Plano Contas].[Plano de Contas].[Totalizadora 4].&[1]&[69552],[Measures].[Saldo Final]) +
        ( [Plano Contas].[Plano de Contas].[Totalizadora 4].&[2]&[69463],[Measures].[Saldo Final]) +
        ( [Plano Contas].[Plano de Contas].[Totalizadora 4].&[3]&[53054],[Measures].[Saldo Final])  +
        ( [Plano Contas].[Plano de Contas].[Totalizadora 4].&[4]&[63740],[Measures].[Saldo Final]) +
        ( [Plano Contas].[Plano de Contas].[Conta Contábil].&[273],[Measures].[Saldo Final]) +
        ( [Plano Contas].[Conta Contábil].&[464],[Measures].[Saldo Final])
    ),
    (
        ( [Plano Contas].[Plano de Contas].[Totalizadora 4].&[1]&[69552],[Measures].[Saldo Final]) +
        ( [Plano Contas].[Plano de Contas].[Totalizadora 4].&[2]&[69463],[Measures].[Saldo Final]) +
        ( [Plano Contas].[Plano de Contas].[Totalizadora 4].&[3]&[53054],[Measures].[Saldo Final])  +
        ( [Plano Contas].[Plano de Contas].[Totalizadora 4].&[4]&[63740],[Measures].[Saldo Final])
    )
)
```

I believe that my mistake is in the beginning of the "iif" but I don't know how solve this situation.

The key of my Period dimension (20101101) is a numeric field, not a date field.

Answer (score 0):

The IIF condition does not compare the values of the key of the two members but the cube values of the two single member tuples (using the current/default [Measures]).

Assuming we can compare directly the values of these keys (it looks like the numeric format yyyymmdd is fine for that) you could do the following using the [properties](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Properties.html) function :

```
IIF ( [Period].[Period].currentMember.properties( "key", TYPED ) < 20101101 )
```

You can check that [MDX gentle introduction](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html) for more details about MDX notations and concepts.

Comment: Does not worked.

The cube was processed no problems but when I create a analysis using this metric (with this "iif"), the result set returned me "#VALUE" in all cells with this message:

"CurrentMember the function expects a hierarchy expression for the argument 1. 
An expression member was used."

Thanks for your reading tip (MDX Tutorial). I'll read it! 

If somebody have a new tip for solution this my problem, I thank in advance.

Comment: I've edited the statement; you can try with [Period].[Period] : should be the name of the hierarchy.